# Java /dev/urandom configuration

Tags: java, secure-random

Whenever I look up switching Java to using `/dev/urandom` from `/dev/random` most sources mention it should be specified as `/dev/./urandom` as a workaround for a [bug in Java](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6202721). I wonder if this still necessary for `Java 8` and up. Bug description references earlier versions of `Java` and most sources that reference `/dev/./urandom` are not fresh either.

When I run `lsof` on a java process it shows both `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` are opened by Java and the number of open `[u]random` files stays roughly the same regardless of `securerandom.source` configuration setting and/or `-Djava.security.egd` argument and whether `'/./'` is present on the file path or not.

So my question is whether the workaround of inserting `'/./'` into the path is still required with the new versions of Java?